# How to prevent LEDs from flashing when turned ON

Tags: led, control, dimming

I have a custom board to control multiple high-brightness strip LED (ON/OFF and dimming through a potentiometer).
Into this board, I have some strip LED that are continuously ON (**only** dimmable) and some other strip LED that are dimmable **AND** ON/OFF controlable via panel mount selectors.

The dimming through the potentiometer affects all strip LED.

I have this issue where when my LEDs are dimmed (< 50%), when I turn ON my board, they are fully bright for like few milliseconds before returning to their luminosity controlled by the potentiometer.

The same way, when I move a selector, all my LEDs are fully bright for few milliseconds then return to their luminosity controlled by the potentiometer. And this phenomenon affects all my LEDs, not only those which are affected by the selector.

Here is an example (simplified) of how I control the state (ON/OFF) and the brightness of my LEDs. The LEDs that are only dimmable doesn't have the P-MOSFET part (not shown here).

[image: Simplified schematic]

- SIG_LED1 is connected to a switch that pulls the signal to ground to turn ON the P-MOSFET Q19 when switched.
- SIG_LED2 is connected to another switch that pulls the signal to ground to turn ON the P-MOSFET Q21 when switched.
- V_POT is connected to the wiper of a 10K potentiometer and its value ranges from 0V to 1.8V.
- The TEST signal is used to turn ON all LED independantly of the panel mount selectors state.

My board is power supplied with 28VDC (I use an AC/DC converter to generate the 28VDC).
The 28VDC is used to generate 3.3V and 1.8V through LDO. The 3.3V is used to power supply OP AMP. The 1.8V is used for the potentiometer.

The phenomenon is very brief but higly annoying. Do you have an idea on how I could prevent this? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is you need a current to flow for -ve terminal to be referenced to pot.  Off and -ve terminal is effectively 0.  Any voltage on pot and high gain of op-amp means base voltage of BJT is fully On.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I don't really understand what you are saying. Could you explain ?

Comment: What is the voltage at the -ve terminal of op-amp when the FET is Off?  Measure it! 
Essentially 0V.  Pot is not 0V.  So what is output of op-amp?  Measure it!  Max.  When your FET turns On, current flows, BJT On max until negative terminal increases to pot.  Your flash of light.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Oh ok I get it, thanks ! I'll try to improve that. But what about the strip LED that doesn't have any FET (they are continuously ON, only the BJT is present) and that are also affected by this phenomenon when another switch not related to this strip LED is used ? Could it be a result of a disturbance in the circuit that would be the consequence of the problem you mention ?

Comment: No idea.   I'd buffer the potentiometer with a voltage follower.